# Dropping rows with duplicate string values in the DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

This is my first problem! I'll try to explain it as clearly as possible:

I have a Series with a DateTimeIndex like this:

[image: DateTime Series]

---

And I need a function that checks the **"day" value** of the date (e.g. 2020-01-**13** 12:00:00) and **REMOVES** that record **IF** the **day value** matches the day value of the **PREVIOUS** record, example:

| **Datetime** | **Description** | **Action** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-13 11:00:00 | 1st record has no previous record to compare to | **MOVE ON** |
| 2020-01-13 12:00:00 | 2nd record has the same "day" value as previous | **DROP RECORD** |
| 2020-01-13 13:00:00 | 3rd record has the same "day" value as previous? | **ALSO DROP RECORD** |
| 2020-01-14 11:00:00 | 4th record has a unique "day" value compared to previous | **MOVE ON** |
| 2020-02-10 11:00:00 | 5th record has a unique "day" value compared to previous | **MOVE ON** |
| 2020-03-20 10:00:00 | 6th record has a unique "day" value compared to previous | **MOVE ON** |
| 2020-06-03 10:00:00 | 7th record has a unique "day" value compared to previous | **MOVE ON** |
| 2020-06-03 12:00:00 | 8th record has the same "day" value compared to previous | **DROP RECORD** |

---

Notice how the drops need to be in sequential order so that only the **first** **unique time of day** remains in the series (the later times of the same day get dropped). In other words, I want there to be only **one record per day** (per month), and that record needs to be the **first time of the day**. Same "day" values for **different** **months** is allowed!

Also keep in mind, I will be applying this function to **hundreds** of other Series just like this one (in fact, each unique Series will be part of a List).

I'm sure this is much harder than it seems. For example, you probably can't use some type of [n-1] .loc index to tell the function to compare to the previous index location if you've already dropped a record, because you'd be telling it to look at a missing record? Complicated!

Comment: My suggestion: split the datetime into two columns, date and time, by creating a new column. Then use df.groupby('date').first().

Comment: Thank you for my very first reply, that sounds quite logical. I will add this suggestion to my notes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a new column, with `date` instead of `datetime`, and drop the duplicates based on that column.

Create column with Date as type.

```py
df['Dates'] = df1['DT'].dt.date
```

Drop duplicates based on **Dates** column, and keep only first occurrence.

```py
drop_duplicates('Dates', keep='first')
```

To see the result:
`df`

If you want, then drop the new column you created, like this:

```py
df = df.drop(['Dates'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Currently trying to convert the newly added 'Dates' column values from 'TimeStamp' to 'Date' types, before seeing if the [drop duplicates keep=first] will do the job. Not sure why I couldn't create the column as Date type to begin with, but working on it.

Comment: `df1['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Dates'])` to convert to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, this will work:

```
#Convert series to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(series)

#Convert datetime strings to datetime format
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

#Create date column by splitting your current date_time column
df['date'] = df['date_time'].dt.date

#Create time column 
df['time'] = df['date_time'].dt.time

#Sort values by the date column, then the time column
df = df.sort_values(by=['date','time'],ascending='True')

#Then group by date and select the first instance for each grouping
new_df = df.groupby('date').first()
```

Comment: I'm going to try your method too, because you put in the effort for me, thank you